# How use arabic letters with english letters and numbers in regular expression

Tags: php, regex, arabic, farsi

I use below code to have something like this: " محمد125 hasan ". with a limit of being between 3 and 25 characters.
but it doesn't work.

```
(^[ \d\p{Arabic}a-zA-Z0-9 ]{3,25}$)
```

Comment: Is preceding and trailing space part of match too ?

Comment: @noob: Guess so, at least it is part of the Initial try (see in square brackets).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plain and simple:

```
^[\d\p{L}\h]{3,25}$
# match the start (^), digits or any letter 
# and horizontal space three to 25 times
# end of the string/line ($)
```

In `PHP` this would be:

```
$string = 'محمد125 hasan ';
$regex = '~^[\d\p{L}\h]{3,25}$~';
if (preg_match($regex, $string, $match) {
    // do sth. useful here
}
```

See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/sA1dH1/2).

Answer (score 0):

Just use \w with `u` modifier which means unicode

```
/^[ \d\p\wa-zA-Z0-9 ]{3,25}$/u
```

https://regex101.com/r/mC5uT3/1

Comment: May I have you Skype account?

Comment: @Shafizadeh same as you;) Tabriz